# Why is my <td> content causing other <td>s to grow?

Tags: html, css

Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wd9G8/1/

Whenever I try to add content to the "Problem Widget", it causes the bottom row of tds to grow.

To be more specific, I want to add a div with a slideshow plugin like below:

```
<div id="my-slideshow" class = "slides">
  <ul class="bjqs">
    <li><a href=""><img src="images/photos/pic.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="images/photos/pic.jpg" /></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The content of the TD is not bigger than the TD itself. The TD shouldn't be struggling to find space to put the content. If you add a simple br tag or two, you can already see the bottom row growing.

Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong? (aside from using tables for layout).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: tables have to except any content within them, which will force the table to grow in width or height, based on what content is inside the TD's

Answer (score 0):

Since the Problem Widget ends at the bottom of the table, as soon as it grows, the lowest row must grow with it. Because the "Problem Widget" is also on the lowest row.

This is just the way tables work.

You can either make the "Problem Widget" one row lower, so the bottom row will be pushed off, instead of extended, or you can set a height for the td's, higher than it will become.

Apart from that, the only better solution I can think of is rebuilding in div's, but I assume that is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I can help you very much on this one, but a way to prevent the tds pushing the others aside with content is setting all tds a width, and make the sum of the widths be equivalent to the table's width.

For example:

table = width:400px;
td1 = width:50px;
td2 = width:250px;
td3 = width:100px;

I believe the same idea works for its height.

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, as you can see in the fiddle, I do specify fixed heights for all the tds. And I specify the fixed-layout attribute too, all to no avail.

Comment: I've seen you are working with percentage values. Does changing it to pixels work?

Comment: I'm using percentage values because I need the table to always be the exact size of the screen, so pixel values won't work in this case.

Comment: I see, in fact I don't trust tables to go the responsive way. Try using an overlapping div on the tds you don't want to break, adding a float:left; and a min-width maybe. Otherwise, I think you should change all to divs.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

HTML

```
<td rowspan="2">
<div id="my-slideshow" class = "slides">
<ul class="bjqs">
     <li><a href=""><img src="images/photos/pic.jpg" /></a></li>
     <li><a href=""><img src="images/photos/pic.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</td><!-- The Problem TD -->
```

CSS

```
.bjqs{
    margin:0 !important;
}
```

The problem is ul's margin(top and bottom).

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work unfortunately. You can add pretty much anything into that TD and it'll still cause the bottom row to grow. It's not just limited to ul.